# How to get all results from another table in a single field for each row based on ID

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to get in a single string all the names of the stores where each brand is specifically sold.

These are my tables:

```
Table: tbproduct
+---------+-----------+--------------+------------+--------+----------+
| prod_id | prod_name |   prod_brand | prod_price | cat_id | store_id |
+---------+-----------+--------------+------------+--------+----------+ 
|    1    |   Hat1    |     Brand1   |     20     |   15   |    1     | 
|    2    |   Hat2    |     Brand2   |     100    |   15   |    1     | 
|    3    |   Hat3    |     Brand3   |     100    |   15   |    2     |
+---------+-----------+--------------+------------+--------+----------+

Table: tbstores
+----------+-------------+ 
| store_id |  store_name |
+----------+-------------+ 
|     1    |   Store1    | 
|     2    |   Store2    |
+----------+-------------+
```

This is the code that I'm using so far in MySQL (PHPMyAdmin):

````
```SQL
SELECT tbproduct.prod_brand as Brand,
concat(min(format(tbproduct.prod_price,0)), ' USD') as Price,
(GROUP_CONCAT(
           DISTINCT tbstores.store_name 
           ORDER BY tbstores.store_name 
           ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
) as Stores
FROM tbproduct, tbstores
WHERE tbproduct.cat_id = '15'
GROUP BY tbproduct.prod_brand
````

So far, I get the single string (the field called 'Stores') with the names of ALL the stores:

```
+----------+-----------+--------------------+
|  Brand   |   Price   |        Stores      |
+----------+-----------+--------------------+
|  Brand1  |   20 USD  |   Store1, Store2   |
|  Brand2  |   100 USD |   Store1, Store2   |
+----------+-----------+--------------------+
```

What I need is to get the single string, but ONLY with the names of the stores where the brand is sold:

```
+----------+-----------+--------------------+
|  Brand   |   Price   |        Stores      |
+----------+-----------+--------------------+
|  Brand1  |   20 USD  |   Store1           |
|  Brand2  |   100 USD |   Store1, Store2   |
+----------+-----------+--------------------+
```

You can find a working sample in this Mysql Fiddle: 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4CxgsQMAeuBGsQ5yLrTXmV/1#&togetherjs=3L1gnCbrA6

Any ideas what can be wrong or how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the join condition in your query. This is the biggest problem with old join syntax. I have converted your query to proper explicit join syntax and used alias to make the query more readable -

```
SELECT tp.prod_brand as Brand,
       concat(min(format(tp.prod_price,0)), ' USD') as Price,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ts.store_name ORDER BY ts.store_name ASC SEPARATOR ', ') as Stores
FROM tbproduct tp
JOIN tbstores ts on tp.store_id = ts.store_id
WHERE tp.cat_id = '15'
GROUP BY tp.prod_brand
```